# In JQuery how to read the key name from JSON String?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tried a lot but not get any proper answer

```
for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
   alert("key name " + data[i].id);
}
```

Comment: What JSON string? There's no JSON in your question. You seem to have an array, `data`, which seems to contain objects, but you don't give us any clues about what its elements might be. Perhaps the point is that you don't know the structure, but still you need to provide more of an explanation about what you want to do. Please [edit] your question and add a sample input and what output you would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` function to access key from an object.

```
var someObject = { 'test1' : '1', 'test2' : '2' };

var objectKeys = Object.keys( someObject );

console.log( "KEY 1: " + objectKeys[0] );
console.log( "KEY 2: " + objectKeys[1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    key: "value",
    second_key: "value2"
};
for (item in data) {
    alert(item + data[item]);
}
```

Try that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse the main object using `json.parse( )` and then iterate.
You can access the objects using `"."` Or  `[ ]`.
For e.g.. In your case it can be `data[i].id` . For getting keyname of json you can try

```
data[i].split(":").[0]
```

in for loop

Comment: Actualy I need Key Name whatever it has